# Removing elements from a key/value subview of Map?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

How can I get a subview of Map then cross elements off it, Gave it a whirl in vain.
Here's my snippet of code :

```
HashMap<String,Integer> myLinkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>(1,1,true);         
myLinkedHashMap.put("a", 2);
myLinkedHashMap.put("b", 3);
myLinkedHashMap.put("c", 4);
Set keysView =  myLinkedHashMap.keySet();
keysView.remove("a");  // worked without a hitch     
Collection valuesView =  myLinkedHashMap.values();
valuesView.remove(4);  // like the last one
```

Here's what my question comes down to :

```
Set<Entry<String,Integer>> associationsView = myLinkedHashMap.entrySet();
associationsView.remove("Nothing doing,for set does not know about key/value thing");
```

Lending a hand would be far appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what do u want to remove from the `associationsView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do? Would something like this work?

```
final Iterator<Entry<String,Integer>> iter = myLinkedHashMap.entrySet().iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
  final Entry<String,Integer> entry = iter.next();
  if(entry.getKey().equals("something")) {
    iter.remove();
  }
}
```

It might also be worth taking a look at the Guava [Maps](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html) class, this has many ways if filtering maps.

Comment: Yes, You hit the nail on the head, I'm figuring on study Guava soon, But after knowing the nuts and bolts of collections first, I can't thank you enough .